# What brand shelving is this?

Tags: shelving

I have some office shelving included in my new home, all of the labels were removed (looks nice, doesn't help me now)

[image: shelf]

[image: shelf]

Comment: It looks like common twin-slot shelf standards. Since there are a million manufacturers I doubt you'll get a confident brand answer.

Comment: yeah that's what I'm afraid of, trying to match the color/size, I want to add one shelf.

Comment: Try looking at the top & bottom of the uprights to see if there is a manufacturer name stamped in. It might actually be on the _inside_ of the upright (necessitating removal from the wall). Barring that, just take your lone bracket (that you took the pic of) to the store, find an upright that it will fit into, and buy more brackets of that brand. As it stands, though, this is basically a "shopping recommendation" question which is OT...

Comment: Have you thought of finding one that fits and spray painting it to match?

Comment: also some of them look very similar but don't fit, there is no standardization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [KV shelving](https://www.cabinetparts.com/p/knape-and-vogt-shelf-hardware-standards-and-brackets-KV182WH9-p29353?gclid=CjwKCAjwrcH3BRApEiwAxjdPTeZrba1VS1GtWqQDSFyX-vvNuow00UqI5MOEMvhLy-zgG3NGCvkYORoC0VQQAvD_BwE). Try KV #182. They come in various lengths and colors.

Answer (score 0):

The shelf support bracket looks to me like it could be elfa. Where I live Dallas TX it is sold at the Container Store.

Comment: We have one of those here in Raleigh also, will have to check and see if they work too, Thanks!